# Why is Progress bar in Ionic 3 not working?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I tried to implement a progress bar in Ionic 3 application following [This Reference Link](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/)  but am getting the following error.

> Runtime Error:Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'progress' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'progress-bar'.1. If 'progress-bar' is an
>   Angular component and it has 'progress' input, then verify that it is
>   part of this module. 2. If 'progress-bar' is a Web Component then add
>   'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. 3. To allow any property add
>   'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("u,
>   including the respective address and opening hours
>
> ][progress]=50>
>    "): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@21:22
>   'progress-bar' is not a known element: 1. If 'progress-bar' is an
>   Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If
>   'progress-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to
>   the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   ("trooms near you, including the respective address and opening
>   hours 
>  [ERROR ->]  "):
>   ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@21:8

I have created a component with the name `ProgressBarComponent` as indicated in the tutorial the code for ts file is

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'progress-bar',
  templateUrl: 'progress-bar.html'
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {

  @Input('progress') progress;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

I am unable to figure out the error as the same code seems to work fine for others but not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your **`ProgressBarComponent`**  inside your module declarations,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [

    ],
    declarations: [
      ProgressBarComponent
   ]
})
```

Comment: Already done but its not working, I have followed the steps as indicated in the reference link but it does not works for me.

Comment: Definitely this is an issue with not registering  component can you create a plunker or stackblitz

Comment: Here Goes the Link https://plnkr.co/edit/YueuYLPVLMPE7WYhDK1I?p=catalogue

Comment: I just pasted the files for reference not familier enough with plunker for code execution please let me check and update.

Comment: @OshoParth How exactly did this resolved your issue?

Comment: @Stranger Not sure that the issue was due to this as I already declared that in my app component file but the things worked when I did it again maybe there was some spell issue as I still haven't found the cause for the bug, although didn't workaround much as it got resolved somehow.